# Registering an event participant, using Entity Framework and several associated models

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository

I have a method that is responsible for receiving an object and perform the information saved with Entity Framwork, using the Repository pattern. The issue is that this object is, basically, a DTO. The information contained in this object must be assigned to the models managed by the data layer, which is a bit confusing to me with respect to the way of making said assignments, considering that there are conditions for some of them.

```
public int RegisterParticipant(ParticipantDTO participant)
{
    try
    {
        EventoParticipante participante = new EventoParticipante();
        if(participant.Token != null)
        {
            var result = RegistrarPagoEnLinea(participant);
            participante.PagoEnLinea = true;
        }
        else
        {
            participante.PagoEnLinea = false;
            participante.TransaccionFecha = DateTime.Now;
            participante.TransaccionCodigo = participant.PaymentRefNumber;
        }
        participante.PersonaId = CreateNaturalPerson(participant).Id;
        participante.InstitucionId = short.Parse(CreateInstitution(participant).ToString());
        participante.EventoId = participant.EventId;
        participante.TipoParticipanteId = _attendeeTypeRepository.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Nombre == participant.TypeParticipant).Id;                
        participante.MontoPago = decimal.Parse(participant.Ammount);
        participante.Asistio = false;
        participante.FechaRegistro = DateTime.Now;
        participante.MontoPago = decimal.Parse(participant.Ammount) - 100;
        _eventAttendeeRepository.Add(participante);
        _eventAttendeeRepository.SaveChanges();
        Evento eventParticipant = _eventRepository.Get(participant.EventId);

        if (participant.CompanionName != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(participant.CompanionName))
        {
            Persona companion = new Persona();
            companion.Nombres = participant.CompanionName;
            companion.Apellidos = participant.CompanionLastName;
            companion.NumeroDocumento = participant.CompanionIdentity;
            companion.Ciudad = participant.AttendeeCity;
            companion.Activo = true;
            companion.UsuarioCreacion = "demo";
            companion.UsuarioModificacion = "demo";
            companion.FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now;
            companion.FechaModificacion = DateTime.Now;
            _personRepository.Add(companion);
            _personRepository.SaveChanges();

            EventoParticipante companionParticipant = new EventoParticipante();
            companionParticipant.PersonaId = companion.Id;
            companionParticipant.EventoParticipanteId = participante.Id;
            companionParticipant.EventoId = participante.EventoId;
            companionParticipant.MontoPago = decimal.Parse((100.00).ToString());
            companionParticipant.TipoParticipanteId = 4;
            companionParticipant.InstitucionId = participante.InstitucionId;
            companionParticipant.Asistio = false;
            companionParticipant.FechaRegistro = DateTime.Now;
            _eventAttendeeRepository.Add(companionParticipant);
            _eventAttendeeRepository.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (participant.InvoiceIdentity != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(participant.InvoiceIdentity))
        {
            CreateInvoice(participant, participante);
            MailHelper.SendMail(MailAction.EventRegisterSuccessWithInvoice, eventParticipant, participant, _countryRepository.Get(participant.AttendeeCountryId).Nombre, _countryRepository.Get((int)participant.InvoiceCountryId).Nombre);
        }
        else
            MailHelper.SendMail(MailAction.EventRegisterSuccess, eventParticipant, participant, _countryRepository.Get(participant.AttendeeCountryId).Nombre);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method is excessively long. I understand that a method should be in charge of a specific function, so I know that it is wrong from that point.

To try to diminish its extension (and the possibility of errors in it) I have separated certain assignment tasks into methods within the same class, as in the case of `CreateNaturalPerson` (yes, the method was even longer). I thought to do the same with the IF where the values are assigned to `Persona` and `EventoParticipante`, but I think it would be to fall into the same. Is there any design pattern or advice for the above mentioned?

Comment: You call `SaveChanges` twice. What happens if the first call succeeds and the second fails? Your db would be left in an invalid state. Also, using return codes is not a c# convention. Just let exceptions be thrown and caught by a global handler. Wrapping huge chunks of code in `try/catch` without logging the exception will just silently mask them, which is really bad.

Comment: Thanks, @BradM. I understood that `SaveChanges` saved the data in the database for each context. I considered that, having an instance of my main `Repository` class for each model of my database, I should make the call each time I made an `Add`. In addition, I had to obtain the ID of the saved item in order to assign it to a property of the following models. Is there any way to do it in a more effective way and considering everything you tell me?

Comment: Why check for `null` and then `string.IsNullOrEmpty`: `if (participant.CompanionName != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(participant.CompanionName))`? `string.IsNullOrEmpty` already include the `null` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method does too much:

- creates `EventoParticipante`
- creates `Persona` for the `companion` if necessary
- creates `EventoParticipante` for the `companion` if necessary
- `CreateInvoice`
- `SendMail`

Each of the first three should be a method or even a class of their own (especially considering each process seems to be fairly complicated), and then this `RegisterParticipant` method should perhaps be a class of its own to combine the individual parts as a process.

This one method is 60+ lines. That is already hard to keep an overview of, and it makes me wonder what other methods this class contains. Focus on making your methods simpler, apply SOLID,...

---

The mix of English and Spanish(?) as class names and method names and variable names is IMHO a bad idea.

---

Why do you do this: `decimal.Parse((100.00).ToString());`?

Ditto: `short.Parse(CreateInstitution(participant).ToString());`: why not simply have `CreateInstitution` return a `short`?

In the same vein: `decimal.Parse(participant.Ammount);`. Why isn't `Ammount` a decimal? (BTW this is spelled incorrectly, the correct word is "Amount".)

Such odd castings are all over your code, see also: `(int)participant.InvoiceCountryId`.

---

This will throw an exception if `_attendeeTypeRepository` cannot find anything:

```
_attendeeTypeRepository.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Nombre == participant.TypeParticipant).Id;
```

Is that something you want?

---

Don't do this:

```
MailHelper.SendMail(MailAction.EventRegisterSuccessWithInvoice, 
   eventParticipant, 
   participant, 
   _countryRepository.Get(participant.AttendeeCountryId).Nombre, 
   _countryRepository.Get((int)participant.InvoiceCountryId).Nombre);
```

Even though it's only five parameters (which is already an amount that is bordering on my upper limit before I'd replace this with a custom class), at least two of these are the result of returns from other methods, and now you have a single line that is 250+ characters. This makes your code hard to read and follow.

Considering that you already pass `participant`, you could easily make a method that only accepts `MailAction` and `participant`, gets the other data itself, and then calls `MailHelper.SendMail`.

---

What does "4" mean in this context: `companionParticipant.TipoParticipanteId = 4;`? Avoid unexplained magic numbers: give them proper names or at least add a comment.